# Node JS Import Alias

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to have an import alias '@/' for my folder 'src/*' in my express js. can someone help me how to do it in the latest setup available? here are my files:

tsconig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "sample-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The core back-end of the sample-project system.",
  "main": "dist/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "prisma:create": "npx prisma migrate dev --create-only",
    "prisma:deploy": "npx prisma migrate deploy",
    "prisma:generate": "npx prisma generate",
    "prisma:seed": "ts-node prisma/seed.ts",
    "setup": "npm install && npm run prisma:deploy && npm run prisma:generate && npm run prisma:seed",
    "update": "npm install && npm run prisma:deploy && npm run prisma:generate",
    "build": "tsc",
    "lint": "npx eslint . --ext .ts",
    "dev": "nodemon src/app.ts",
    "start": "node"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.5",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.19.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.19.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.3",
    "prisma": "^5.8.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.8.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1"
  }
}
```

I'm struggling to find the best settings. Thank you for those who can help.